# Using RegEx in Obj-C: Isolating grocery items in a recipe ingredient

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to use regex to filter out measurements, preparation information, and other adjectives in cooking recipe ingredients. I want the following result:

When given:

`1 cup (3oz) sliced carrots, cut lengthwise`

I want:

`carrots`

Using the Mac app "Patterns" to work on the regex, the following expression is working as desired:

```
(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<! cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[(0-9)+(oz)?])\b
```

However, when I use this in the following code, there are no matches - the "matches" array is empty:

```
NSString *phrase = [NSString stringWithString:@"1 cup (3oz) sliced carrots, cut lengthwise"];

NSRegularExpression *nameExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<! cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[(0-9)+(oz)?])\b" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [nameExpression matchesInString:phrase
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [phrase length])];
```

I am setting the practice app to use Obj-C as the target language. Why aren't I getting any matches?

Update: I have discovered that the `?<word>` is extraneous, and that the problem lies with the `?<!` sequence of characters. Again, the expression

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<! cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[(0-9)+(oz)?])\b
```

works in my objective-c regex tester, but not in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

```
(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<! cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[(0-9)+(oz)?])\b 
 ^^^^^^^                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
 1                                                  2
```

1. The [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) makes no mention of "named capture groups", which is what this is. Perhaps they are not supported.
2. Currently this matches any string comprised of the characters `0123456789oz+()?`. I don't think that's what you meant; you probably want to remove the outer square brackets, and surround the `0-9` with them.

This would leave you with:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<! cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[0-9]+(oz)?)\b
```

**EDIT:**

Can't have unbounded lookbehind assertions. Use a lookahead instead (and I'm improving your expression a bit):

```
\b(?!(?:cut|cup|sliced|lengthwise|[0-9]+(?:oz)?)\b)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Here's [a Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/0TLAPtr0EK).

Comment: With additional testing, I too found that the "?<word>" is not necessary, the expression seems to run the same when it is removed. But your solution shows a syntax error in my tester, and fails in my code as well.

Comment: Oh, I know why. You can't have unbounded-length lookbehind assertions. See edit; let's use lookahead assertions instead.

Answer (score 2):

@acheong87 already pointed out the problem with `[(0-9)+(oz)?]`.  Like Java, NSRegularExpression allows you to use a complex expression in a lookbehind as long as it can determine the maximum number of characters it can match.  `[(0-9)+(oz)?]` only consumes one character, so each alternative inside the lookbehind has a fixed length.  With the correct version, `[0-9]+(?:oz)?`, that's no longer true.

But lookbehind wasn't the right tool for this job anyway.  (It almost never is; lookbehind is probably the second most abused regex feature, after `.*?`.)

If the corrected regex works in the tester but not in your code, look to the word boundaries.  You have `@"\b"` in your sample code, which is probably being interpreted as a backspace character.  What you should be using is `@"\\b"`.

Comment: Wish I could hand out rep to you as well - escaping the word boundary was key to finding the solution.

Comment: @MattMiller - We can both upvote Alan's solution, at the least :)